# How to synchronize concurrently running tests in xUnit?

Tags: c#, testing, nunit, xunit

I need to start in parallel potentially tens of test cases, but there is a catch - all of them reach a point where a single action should be performed only once, regardless of how many test cases are running. Once this action is over, the tests can resume and continue running independently.

Right now I have the following implementation in NUnit:

```
[TestFixture]
public class ScheduleJobTest
{
    private static readonly Subject<Unit> s_tickets = new Subject<Unit>();

    [OneTimeSetUp]
    public static void SetUp()
    {
        Task.Run(() => s_tickets
            .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
            .SelectMany(_ => PollSchedulesNow())
            .DefaultIfEmpty()
            .GetAwaiter()
            .GetResult());
    }

    [OneTimeTearDown]
    public static void TearDown()
    {
        s_tickets.OnCompleted();
    }

    private static IObservable<Unit> PollSchedulesNow()
    {
        // Do something that eventually unblocks all the test cases
    }

    [TestCaseSource(nameof(ProvideNamespaces)), Parallelizable(ParallelScope.Children)]
    public void ScheduleJob(NamespaceConnectionInfo nci)
    {
        // Do something
        s_tickets.OnNext(Unit.Default);
        // Resume - blocks until the actions of PollSchedulesNow take effect
    }

    private static IEnumerable<TestCaseData> ProvideNamespaces()
    {
        return ...
    }
}
```

Each test case queues a ticket for the special action that should be done just once. The throttling makes sure that as long as the tickets arrive within at most one second time interval nothing happens. But as soon as a pause occurs, it triggers that special action. If, for some reason, there will be more test cases after that pause, then the special action will be called again - which is fine. I just do not want it to be called 100 times for 100 concurrent test cases running at the same time.

This is the best I could come up with in NUnit. Is there a better way to implement it in xUnit? Or maybe I need a different framework in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off: No. There is no way in NUnit to coordinate across tests unless you write the coordinating code yourself, in the tests. Even then, you would have to ensure that NUnit runs all of them together, which it may or may not do without your help.

But yes! You can accomplish what you want. You are trying to model what is essentially a single test across multiple threads using multiple NUnit tests. Don't do that! Write a single test that spawns as many separate threads as you want. Wait for them to complete and then verify that the action was only performed once. There's only one assertion here, which kind of proves there is only one test.

You can repeat this for varying numbers of threads and error conditions, as many times as you like. Each of those variations would be a single test.

Comment: I need to have multiple test cases. The test is a deployment smoke test - it asserts that schedules are polled correctly for a client. From the user perspective they are independent tests - one per client. There is implementation detail though - the schedules are polled by a multi-tenant background service and this polling is triggered by a record in a single database serving the multi-tenant pod. I can create a record per client and it will work, but it will stress that service and I want to avoid it.

Comment: If you have to do it that way, then put all the tests in a fixture with no other tests. Initialize in OneTimeSetUp and make your check in OneTimeTearDown.

Comment: But then the special action is either in the beginning of all the tests or at the end of all the tests. In my case, it is in the middle. The tests reach a rendezvous point waiting for the special action to complete and then resume to run until their completion.

Comment: The special action is in your production code, not the tests. Checking that the special action was done only once at the appropriate moment can be done in your TestFixtureTearDown, assuming your tests save that information.